# Querying for all Standard and Custom Objects

Tags: apex, soql, lightning-aura-components, custom-object, standard-objects

Is there a way to get a list of all Standard and Custom Objects in an organization through SOQL or other means?

I'm trying to create a table list to show all Standard and Custom Objects as a flexible way for an admin to choose what to show a particular user in a Lightning Component.

Comment: Have you considered [Schema.getGlobalDescribe()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_global_describe.htm#apex_dynamic_global_describe)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You surely can using `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`, as mentioned in the comments. It returns a `Map<String, SObjectType>`, so you can get a `Set<String> objectNames` or a `List<SObjectType>` quite easily from it, among other uses. For instance, you could easily use it to generate a `List<SelectOption>` for use in a classic `Visualforce Page`:

```
List<SelectOption> objects = new List<SelectOption>();
for (SObjectType sObjectType : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values())
    objects.add(new SelectOption(
        String.valueOf(sObjectType),
        sObjectType.getDescribe().getLabel()
    );
```